# Should my SharePoint central administration site have the same port number as the other SharePoint web applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have defined during SharePoint installation that the port for the central administration site is 5555, and when I create a new web application I define the port number to be 2013. But now the central administration and the web application will be on separate ports numbers.  so which approach I should follow; to have the central admin and the other application on the same port or they should have different ports numbers as I am doing now? 
Second question is there a way to edit the web application port number after creating it?
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ports is preferred. For consistancy, if you have dev/qa/staging environments, you should keep the CA and SP sites on the same ports across those farms so it's easy to remember.

Answer (score 3):

If you have set central admin and web applications to have the same port, you'll need to configure host headers for each so that IIS knows how to handle requests to each (Central Admin and a web application cannot co-exist on the same IIS web site).

You can modify the web application port number after it is created by changing the binding settings on the IIS web site, and configuring alternate access mappings in central admin.